# Overwrite behavior of SharePoint 2013 task list 'status' column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

How can I overwrite behavior of SharePoint 2013 task list 'status' column, which sets 100% task to "Completed" status.

I need to set 100% as well as my custom status "CustomCompleted"

But somehow I am not able to achieve the same, I am able to set percentage and status but it does not work smoothly.

Comment: Can you explain further what is your current approach and problem you are facing?

Comment: I just want to set '%percent' and 'Status' both by my own custom values, but SP seems to override it and sets '100%' thing to 'Completed' status

Comment: This is an out of the box feature when you update the item with your custom status and percent. There is an event triggering and updating status to 'Completed' when you set % Completed to 100%. You need to manage with custom columns if need custom status.

Answer (score 3):

That behaviour is programmed by Microsoft

All this applies to Language Localized values as well

- `% Complete` is set to 0 when you set the `Status` to `Not Started`
- `% Complete` is set to 100 when you set the `Status` to `Completed`
- `% Complete` is set to 50 when you set the `Status` to **any other value**

This is rather annoying behaviour when you add an extra Status value and do not want the `% Complete` changed.
In our case we added a 'Next Sprint' Status, and we had to add an *On-Change* Workflow to reset the `% Complete` back to 0 for a 'Next Sprint' Status

#### [Completed] is not a regular Calculated Column

It has special code behind it, which displays the checkbox

- when checked the `Status` is changed to `Completed` and `% Complete` set to 100
- when unchecked the `Status` is changed to `Not Started` and `% Complete` set to 0

Nowadays with SP2013 this checkbox w/could have been done with CSR - Client Side Rendering.

Note: The `% complete` **value** is actually between 0 and 1; so 50% = 0.5
In case you want to use it in other Calculated Columns

Comment: Excellent info Danny, thank you!

Comment: tnx, was a blast from the past for me... escaped the Microsoft SP world some years ago :-)